# Como alinhar tabela no HTML?

Tags: html, tabela-html

Simplesmente não alinha

```
<Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Revisão</title>
        <meta charset="utf8"/>
    </head>

    <body>
         <table aling="center" border="1">
            <div>            
                <tr>
                     <td>Nome</td>
                </tr>
            </div> 
            <div>
                <tr>
                    <td>gabriel</td>
                 </tr>
            </div>   
         </table>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Align está escrito errado, e evite as tabelas para formulários. Use a tag form

Answer (score 0):

Você está escrevendo *"aling"* em vez de ***"align"***. É só trocar que centraliza.

```html
<body>
     <table align="center" border="1">
        <div>            
            <tr>
                 <td>Nome</td>
            </tr>
        </div> 
        <div>
            <tr>
                <td>gabriel</td>
             </tr>
        </div>   
     </table>

</body>
```

Comment: perguntas que tenham um erro tipografico devem ser fechadas e nao respondidas

Comment: sabia não. Inclusive, já vi várias perguntas cujo erro era tipográfico sendo respondidas e continuando abertas aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Oie, você escreveu Align errado. 
Uma dica, tabelas dão dor de cabeça demais, só use-as quando não tiver outra escolha :D

```
<table align="center" border="1">
```